# How to apply a ring-middleware to specific group of routes?

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I have a ring middleware which does some check on request maps with the header values.
For the check I have to hit the database.

If a defroutes as a set of routes starting with acommon URI pattern.
I don't want a middleware to run for any random URL that matches the pattern before getting handled.

I only want middleware to run for a certain set of URIs that I am suing inside of defroutes only. The reason being there is a database access in the middleware which I want to avoid for 404 responses having the same pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [comporoute](http://github.com/lgrapenthin/comporoute), a ring handler without any macro magic, aimed at composability and extensibility.

Even though it's in early alpha state it has precise docstrings already. It has a feature called *inner middleware* to solve the issue you are having. You may (and should) use it only for what you need it for and leave the rest to Compojure.

Given your Compojure handler/app is called `compojure`:

```
(defn demo-middleware 
  "A test midleware associng :bar to :foo of request"
  [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (handler (assoc request :foo :bar))))

(defn demo-handler [request]
  (ring.util.response/response 
     (str "id is " (get-in request [:params :id]) " "
          ":foo is" (:foo request))))

(def app
  (comporoute.core/router
    [["/demo-with-middleware"
      [demo-middleware ;; all handlers in this vector are 
                       ;; wrapped via demo-middleware
       ["/:id" :demo-with demo-handler]]]
     ["/demo-without-middleware" 
       ["/:id" :demo-without demo-handler]]]
    :page-not-found compojure)
```

At the shell

```
curl http://localhost:8080/demo-without-middleware/1234
id is 1234 :foo is

curl http://localhost:8080/demo-with-middleware/1234
id is 1234 :foo is :bar

# Everything else will be handled by compojure.
```

Dependency vector `[comporoute "0.2.0"]`

Comment: Will I have ro re write all my existing route code in this style or just the part where I define (ANY "/xyz/*" [] (my-middleware xyz-routes)))

be replaced with this kind of syntax ?

Comment: I just updated the answer. Just put the routes that need the middleware into a seperate defroutes.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. in your example if I send a request to. db/blahblahblah

and you dont have a /blahblahblah in db-routes, it still first calls the middleware and then checks db-routes for the route and returns 404 if not found.

Comment: You are right. compojure can't solve that. I rolled back to my original answer. You will need to use comporoute only for the routes that are wrapped by the DB, like in the example and may leave the rest to compojure.

Comment: What are :demo-with  abd :demo-without keyword params mean in this example ?

Comment: They aren't params. Comporoute takes only pure functions that have to deal with the entire request map. They are idents that you can use to reconstruct the url via `comporoute.core/url-for`

Comment: Is there a way I can specify the method for these routes ?

Comment: Yes, like described [here](https://github.com/lgrapenthin/comporoute/blob/64630e35855c540004e0566d6740e1af5344a7f2/src/comporoute/core.clj#L265), in the docstring. `["/foo" :foo {:get foo-get, :post foo-post}]` etc.